# How to use comma separator "," instead "." in decimal genexus values?

Tags: genexus

Actually i have one column that store values in `decimal (12.2)` I need to convert this decimal value `59.90` in Brasilian money `59,90`. There's a way to convert or tell to genexus to use `","` instead of `"."` in decimal values?

In genexus documentation i find this:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7670,Decimal+separator+property,

But don't specify how i can change to assume the Comma separator decimal

I try:

```
&ProductRequestPost.price = Val(STR(&price, 15, 2), ",")
```

But in this way i get:

> "price":59,

Answer (score 0):

In GeneXus, the decimal separator is language dependant. In order to customize it, you should open the language object and change the `Decimal Separator` property.

You can find the language objects in the KB Explorer tool window, under Customization > Localization.

To find out your Knowledge Base's default language, click on the root node in the KB Explorer tree and look for the `Kb Language` property.